# ElasticSearch query for uuid field

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I want to query elasticsearch records where one field contains the uuid values in string format. Here is the record structure

```
{
"field1": "test 1",
"field2": "testing 1",
"field3": "c48718a5-d715-4fbd-8a53-40707c83b2ce.eb47d75e-6b2f-403c-9e56-f1569d5b40d0"
},
{
"field1": "test 2",
"field2": "testing 2",
"field3": "c48718a5-d715-4fbd-8a53-40707c83b2ce.eb47d75e-6b2f-403c-9e56-f1569d5b40d0.d0644d62-f079-46ee-ab98-30d8d16977c2"
}
```

my query looks like this

```
{
   "query": {
       "query_string": {
           "query": "(field1:test) AND (field3:c48718a5-d715-4fbd-8a53-40707c83b2ce.eb47d75e-6b2f-403c-9e56-f1569d5b40d0)",
           "default_operator": "and"
       }
   }
}
```

Here is the mapping for the field3

```
"field3": {
           "type": "text",
           "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                 "type": "keyword",
                 "ignore_above": 256     
              }
            }
 }
```

The problem is elasticsearch is sending both the records when i run this query. I only want first record to be fetched. Here elasticsearch is matching the provided string in the field3 but i want the record where field value is equal to the given value.

Please suggest. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are almost there. You just need to use `field3.keyword` instead of `field3`. This uses the keyword analyzer instead of the standard analyzer (notice the ".keyword" after field3 field).

Modify your search query as

```
{
   "query": {
       "query_string": {
           "query": "(field1:test) AND (field3.keyword:c48718a5-d715-4fbd-8a53-40707c83b2ce.eb47d75e-6b2f-403c-9e56-f1569d5b40d0)",
           "default_operator": "and"
       }
   }
}
```

Also, you can remove the `default_operator` from the search query, since you have already added `AND` in the `query` part.